Issue with downloading a zip file in a Java project
I am facing an issue while trying to download a zip file from a link in my Java project. The error I am receiving is as follows:
2024-07-10 07:14:43,678 ERROR [de.fla.emb.pro.run.Starter] (main) Could not open inputStream for https://github.com/nats-io/nats-server/r4-windows-amd64.zip with proxy Optional.empty: java.io.IOException: Could not open inputStream for https://github.com/nats-io/nats-server8.4-windows-amd64.zip with proxy Optional.empty
        at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.UrlConnectionDownloader.downloadInputStream(UrlConnectionDownloader.java:137)
        at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.UrlConnectionDownloader.download(UrlConnectionDownloader.java:72)
        at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.ArtifactStore.checkDistribution(ArtifactStore.java:74)
        at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.ArtifactStore.extractFileSet(ArtifactStore.java:79)
        at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.ExtractedArtifactStore.extractFileSet(ExtractedArtifactStore.java:103)
        at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Starter.prepare(Starter.java:59)
        at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Starter.prepare(Starter.java:52)
        at np.com.madanpokharel.embed.nats.EmbeddedNatsServer.startServer(EmbeddedNatsServer.java:52)
        at com.example.nats.NatsTest.setUp(NatsTest.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.runExtensionMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:1015)
        at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.runExtensionMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:909)
        at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptBeforeAllMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:698)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingE
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:10
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:128)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeAllMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:70)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingE
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:10
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllMethods$13(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:41
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllMethods(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:409)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:215)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:84)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestE
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExec
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.execute(LazyLauncher.java:55)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:223)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:139)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:456)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:169)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:595)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:581)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: github.com
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:572)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:304)
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:533)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:638)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:380)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.ja
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:179)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1665)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
        at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.UrlConnectionDownloader.downloadInputStream(UrlConnectionDownloader.java:133)
        ... 72 more

Here is my code:
  @BeforeAll
  public static void setUp() throws Exception {
    EmbeddedNatsConfig config = new EmbeddedNatsConfig.Builder()
        .withNatsServerConfig(
            new NatsServerConfig.Builder()
                .withServerType(ServerType.NATS)
                .withPort(4222)
                .withNatsVersion(NatsVersion.LATEST)
                .withHost("localhost")
                .build())
        .build();
    natsStreamingServer = new EmbeddedNatsServer(config);
    natsStreamingServer.startServer();
    assertTrue(natsStreamingServer.isServerRunning());

  }

I have verified that the link is working correctly by manually downloading the zip file from the browser, but for some unknown reason, the download fails in my Java project.
I have already checked my internet connection, proxy settings, and project configurations, but the issue persists.
I have performed several checks to resolve the problem, but I have been unsuccessful so far. Here's what I have already verified:
My internet connection is stable and functional.
I do not have a proxy configured that could be blocking the download.
The settings in my Java project are correctly configured to allow file downloads from the internet.
I have tried manually downloading the zip file from the given link and it works without any issues.
Despite these checks, the download still fails in my Java project. Therefore, I am seeking a solution or suggestions to resolve this problem.

If I paste this URL in to my browser I get a 404 error. Are you sure it's correct?

That's the wrong link. THIS is the right one

Scroll through the error; about halfway down you get 'Caused by' and from there a rather obvious: "UnknownHostException: github.com".
Whatever that nats thing is, as part of its code, it downloads a zip from github.com (which is a rather dubious exercise, but you're going to have to take that up with the NATS team) - and this fails, because your java process does not have network access. Perhaps you are on a mac and you retracted its network access, or you've installed a firewall, or otherwise told your OS to do so. Or the system you are running this on has no network. Or it does, but it has a misconfigured DNS server.
The point is, it has nothing to do with java. You've checked lots of things (and mentioned them in the question), which is a great way to go about it - it's reasonable to think it must therefore be java. But, it's not - java has no --disable-firewall option or similar. That error means exactly what it says, no more, and no less.
Next steps:
Eliminate that nats itself is setting up that UrlConnection object with proxies. Write a bare bones java app that just pings github.com:
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("https://github.com");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.connect();
    try (InputStream in = con.getInputStream()) {
      in.transferTo(System.out);
    }
  }
}

(Save that in a file named Test.java, then run java Test.java. Not javac. Run with java; you don't have to compile first).
If it prints the contents of the github homepage, it's either NATS (in which case you might want to check the manual, specifically sections about proxys), or, it's the way you start java when running your project that causes the stacktrace you're asking about vs. how you run the above.
If that still doesn't work, at least you've eliminated NATS as being in any way relevant to the issue. Next try ping github.com in the same command window. If that also doesn't work you've now eliminated java as being in any way relevant. If that does, it's now down to figuring out which OS setting is at fault, though, you want to double check the value of environment variable JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS, as well as _JAVA_OPTIONS - java acts like the values of those env vars are part of the switches you start java with, and java does have a way to configure proxies.
If there's nothing of import there, check your OS firewall settings - firewalls can be configured to deny specific things to specific applications. OSes often have built-in access control tools; for example, macs won't allow any disk access to any app unless you explicitly click 'allow' on the popup that shows the first time you run that app. You may have clicked 'deny' on a similar popup for network access on a completely different app that uses java under the hood, thus telling your OS to 'deny all network traffic to the java executable', and this is the result.

Even simpler: try(InputStream in = new URL("https://github.com").openStream()) { in.transferTo(System.out); }

That's all very interesting but probably more straightforward to use a valid link

@G00se The link may be wrong but it appears to be coming from the NATS source code, i.e. not something the asker can fix, and, the error in the logs is not a 404 error.
